# Difference between weechat and weechat-curses

Tags: irc

I recently started using weechat IRC client on Ubuntu. After the installation the client can be started by either running `weechat` or `weechat-curses` commands. Can someone explain the difference in both?

Answer (score 2):

`weechat` is the more recent version, as described [here in the Wiki (in German)](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WeeChat/#Benutzung)

Comment: could you summarise the contents in English?

Comment: @Zanna The wiki just says which one is the older version. [weechat.org has docs in English](http://weechat.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is the command line version of weechat. The `-curses` references curses which is a programming library, that is used to create  Text User Interfaces (TUI).

You can learn more at:

- [weechat-curses man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/weechat-curses)
- [curses (programming library) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library))

**Edit:** It looks like I did not research this well enough, both commands launch a command line app.

Comment: so... what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed `weechat`. It's v2.4. By checking `/usr/local/bin` directory.

```sh
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep weechat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1205168 Apr  8 11:49 weechat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Apr  8 10:46 weechat-curses -> weechat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1208600 Apr  8 11:49 weechat-headless
```

It is clear that `weechat-curses` is a link to `weechat`. In short, both commands run the same program.

Answer (score 0):

You should run only "weechat".

"weechat-curses" is the legacy binary name, it is a symbolic link to "weechat" and still present for compatibility reasons.